# eception Unclosed quotation mark after the character string . But i have no idea why

Tags: sql, xml, ado.net

I seem to be getting an exception which reads "Incorrect syntax near '00'.
Un-closed quotation mark after the character string ',False )'." what am i doing wrong? It's so hard for me to spot small errors like this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

A bit more detail: I'm using visual studio and SQL server if that helps to narrow down the problem?

```
SqlConnection conn = Database.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand command ;
        SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile ;
        string sql = null;



        int PatientNo=0;
       bool FurtherVisitRequired;
        string AdvisoryNotes=null;
        string Prescription=null;
            string TreatmentProvided=null;
DateTime ActualVisitDateTime;
        string Priority=null;
        DateTime ScheduledDateTime;
        string TreatmentInstructions=null;
        int MedicalStaffID;
        string VisitRefNo=null;


        //conn = new SqlConnection(conn);

        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("\\HomeCareVisit.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
        int i = 0;
        conn.Open();
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            VisitRefNo=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            PatientNo= Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
 ScheduledDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
 TreatmentInstructions = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
  MedicalStaffID= Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4]);
            Priority = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                  ActualVisitDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[6]);
 TreatmentProvided = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
            Prescription = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();


            AdvisoryNotes = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[9].ToString();





           FurtherVisitRequired =Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[10]);








            sql = "insert into HomeCareVisit values(" + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "'," + ScheduledDateTime + "" + TreatmentInstructions + ",'" + MedicalStaffID + "'," + Priority+ "'," + ActualVisitDateTime + ",'" + TreatmentProvided + "'," + Prescription+ "',"+AdvisoryNotes +"',"+FurtherVisitRequired+" )";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
           adpter.InsertCommand = command;
            adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done .. ");
```

Icemand answered the original question.  But his answer has brought a new one.  How do you turn the identity insert on and off in the SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using parameters, and you are not replacing values that contain the string delimiter `"'"`.

You should replace apostrophs in strings, like for example `TreatmentProvided.Replace("'", "''")`.
And you shouldn't build a string in the first place. 
Use parameters.

PS:
You can get it to work with an idendity like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HomeCareVisit] ON
-- insert here:
insert into HomeCareVisit VALUES (" + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "','" + ScheduledDateTime + "','" + TreatmentInstructions + "','" + MedicalStaffID + "','" + Priority+ "','" + ActualVisitDateTime + "','" + TreatmentProvided + "','" + Prescription+ "','"+AdvisoryNotes +"',"+FurtherVisitRequired+" )

-- end insert
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HomeCareVisit] OFF
```

Also, if you are writing table-content back into a database, you can read the xml into a datatable, and then use BulkInsert.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some quotation marks and commas in the following line:

`sql = "insert into HomeCareVisit values(" + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "'," + cheduledDateTime + "" + TreatmentInstructions + ",'" + MedicalStaffID + "'," + Priority+ "'," + ActualVisitDateTime + ",'" + TreatmentProvided + "'," + Prescription+ "',"+AdvisoryNotes +"',"+FurtherVisitRequired+" )";`

The missing quotation marks are around the ScheduledDateTime, Perescription, AdvisoryNotes, TreatmentInstructions, etc. values. You should put quotation marks around the string and datetime variables and you should not put for numbers. The correct code should be:

`sql = "insert into HomeCareVisit values(" + VisitRefNo + ",'" + PatientNo + "','" + ScheduledDateTime + "','" + TreatmentInstructions + "','" + MedicalStaffID + "','" + Priority+ "','" + ActualVisitDateTime + "','" + TreatmentProvided + "','" + Prescription+ "','"+AdvisoryNotes +"',"+FurtherVisitRequired+" )";`

I suggest that you should check your variables type and put the marks around the mentioned variables + take a look on each comma if they are in the right place or they are missing. To make a double check print out the query string before you send it ot the DB that will help you debug your code.

Comment: Thank you iceman. However it is now saying "Invalid column name 'False'.
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HomeCareVisit' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON." do you have any idea how to switch it on so i can insert into the primary key field using the sql command? I know how to do it via SQL server, but not how to code it into the SQL command.